# ARRAY FORM DATA RECEIVED IN PHP

Tags: php

I want to received 4,5 row data in php. When I put values in the form like 3 or 4 row than I want to received the same data in php :(

I am trying to make a pos. When the customer order multiple product than the order row automatically increase but there is no limit 5, 10, 15 or else.

And I want to received the data value in same rows like

```
<form name="data" method="post" action="data_rec.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <input name="data[]" type="text" id="data1" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <input name="data[]" type="text" id="data1" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <input name="data[]" type="text" id="data1" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <input name="data[]" type="text" id="data1" />
    </td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
    <input name="data[]" type="text" id="data1" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <input name="data[]" type="text" id="data1" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <input name="data[]" type="text" id="data1" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <input name="data[]" type="text" id="data1" />
    </td>
  </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>
    <input name="data[]" type="text" id="data1" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <input name="data[]" type="text" id="data1" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <input name="data[]" type="text" id="data1" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <input name="data[]" type="text" id="data1" />
    </td>
  </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>
    <input name="data[]" type="text" id="data1" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <input name="data[]" type="text" id="data1" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <input name="data[]" type="text" id="data1" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <input name="data[]" type="text" id="data1" />
    </td>
  </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>
    <input name="data[]" type="text" id="data1" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <input name="data[]" type="text" id="data1" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <input name="data[]" type="text" id="data1" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <input name="data[]" type="text" id="data1" />
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>

<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="SEND">
</form>




 <?php





    foreach (array_combine($_POST['data'], $_POST['data']) as $i => $data) {
         $i."<br />";
        echo $data."<br />";
        echo "SAGOR"."<br />";
    }


    ?>
```

**Output :**

```
1
SAGOR
2
SAGOR
3
SAGOR
4
SAGOR
5
SAGOR
6
SAGOR
7
SAGOR
8
SAGOR

SAGOR
```

**But I need :**

```
1 2 3 4
SAGOR
5 6 7 8
```

Comment: I recommend not typing in all caps, as it makes your question hard to read.

Comment: your caps lock key is broken

Comment: thx for the edit Zsw. My gosh

Answer (score 0):

You can add rows to your form on the browser with JS or JQuery.
You must give each row's elements unique ids/names like: `<input name="data2" type="text" id="data2" /> <input name="data3" type="text" id="data3" />`...
You will receive them all in you $_POST when the user submit the form